# Find & Replace from a list

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to Find & Replace multiple words in two particular columns.

This code is in part from several I saw around StackOverflow but wouldn't allow me comment so that the original writers could help me out.

Gives me an error 457 in line `.Add RefElem.Value, RefElem.Offset(0, 1).Value` and I don't know why.

```
Sub Cambios()

    Dim Wbk As Workbook: Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Wsht As Worksheet: Set Wsht = Wbk.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as needed.
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim RefList As Range, RefElem As Range
    Dim TargetRng As Range

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set RefList = Wsht.Range("L2:L93") 'Modify as needed.
    Set TargetRng = Union(Wsht.Range("C1:C50"), Wsht.Range("F2:F345")) 'Modify as needed.

    With Dict
        For Each RefElem In RefList
            If Not .Exists(RefElem) And Not RefElem Is Nothing Then
                'ERROR HERE
                .Add RefElem.Value, RefElem.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next RefElem
    End With

    For Each Key In Dict
        With TargetRng
            .Replace What:=Key, Replacement:=Dict(Key)
        End With
    Next Key

    Set Dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

It is meant to replace a list of 92 words with other words, spaces, commas or nothing.

Comment: You are checking if a range object exists as a key, but then adding the range's Value as the key, which is a mis-match comparison.  As a result, the `Not .Exists` will *always* be True and then it tries to add a duplicate key which is causing the 457 error.  Easy fix, add `.Value` to the check exists line: `If Not .Exists(RefElem.Value) Then`

Answer (score 1):

The error comes, because `Add RefElem.Value` is adding an empty string to a dictionary and this is not ok by design. The problem is in the conditional check:

```
If Not .Exists(RefElem) And Not RefElem Is Nothing Then
```

This part can never be TRUE - `RefElem Is Nothing`, because `RefElem` is a range cell, thus it is always "something".

As the code is most probably trying to check whether there is a value in the cell, this is a good work around:

```
If (Not .exists(RefElem.Value2)) And Trim(RefElem) <> "" Then
```

Additionally - consider writing `Option Explicit` [on the top of the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement), thus it would automatically check the declaration of all variables - E.g. in the answer `key` is not declared.

Comment: Ahh thanks! However, the error 457 still persists in `.Add RefElem.Value, RefElem.Offset(0, 1).Value`

Comment: @CGG - strange. What are the values in `Wsht.Range("J1:J3")`?

Comment: "L2:L95" I used that as an example as I was constructing the Excel :)

Comment: @CGG - you may write `Debug.Print RefElem.Value; RefElem.Address
` before the error line to see exactly what is the value and the address of the cell.

Comment: Nothing has changed, only the error 457: The key is already associated with an element in this collection.

Comment: @CGG - try this - `If (Not .exists(RefElem.Value2)) And Trim(RefElem) <> "" Then`

Comment: Now for `For Each Key In Dict` fo rthe word "Key" there is an error Variable not defined

Comment: @CGG - this is because, the `Option Explicit` line is missing from the code. Simply write `Dim key` before the for-each line, but read the Option Explicit link from the answer...

Comment: @CGG - `Option Explicit` only does the check. It tells you which variables are not defined. Once you see them, you have to add them by yourself. It is like an important helper, but it does not add code to the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindReplace()

Dim findthis As Variant
Dim replacewith As Variant
Dim rng As range
Dim x As Long

findthis = Array("Value", "Value2", "Value3")
replacewith = Array("Difval", "Difval2", "Difval3")

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A:A,C:C")

For x = LBound(findthis) To UBound(findthis)
rng.Cells.Replace what:=findthis(x), Replacement:=replacewith(x), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan, thanks! However, it being a list of over 93 I want to avoid having to add each value individually, especially if this list might increase in the future :)

Comment: @CGG no worries, you can point the array to look at a range or a table instead of directly in the code to manage this easier.

Comment: I have tried using .Range and it doesn't seem to work. @Nathan How would you do it? Maybe I am looking at it incorrectly!

Comment: Change a couple things around, could also transpose the array to go down the sheet instead of across:

findthis = Sheets("Sheet1").range("g8:k8").Value
replacewith = Sheets("Sheet1").range("g9:k9").Value
    
rng.Cells.Replace what:=findthis(1, x), Replacement:=replacewith(1, x)